# How to stop all native threads when Android app is backgrounded?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, native-activity, android-threading

My video game is based on NativeActivity and has a lot of C++ threads. I'd like all those threads to pause like they do on iOS when my app is backgrounded. There are simply too many threads to chase them all down at random times.

Does Android NDK/SDK provide a way to do this? And perhaps a way to restart them when the app is foregrounded?